# Stripe Elements for a checkout form using node js and ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments, ejs

I am trying to create an application that allows users to select different subscription levels and pay based on the level they chose. I am using Stripe to handle payments, node.js for server logic, and ejs for rendering my html pages. So far, I am able to create customers and a subscription in Stripe using a sign up form that stores the user's info, however, the subscription is set as inactive by default. This means that after the users sign up, they will be redirected to a checkout page where they can input their credit card info, and I am trying to create the checkout form using the stripe elements. I am following this Stripe tutorial and docs directly from Stripe: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscription?ui=elements#collect-payment
However, the checkout page does not show any indication that the elements is being created as only a subscription button appears with no fields to input the card info. Here is my checkout page:

```
<% include('partials/header') %>

<body>
  <form id="payment-form">
   <div id="card-element">
     <!-- Elements will create input elements here -->
   </div>

   <!-- We'll put the error messages in this element -->
   <div id="card-element-errors" role="alert"></div>
   <button type="submit">Subscribe</button>
 </form>
</body>

<!-- Copyright LFD Banner -->
<div class="container-fluid copyright-banner-container">
  <p class="white-text">&copy Lonestar Firearm Defense 2021</p>
  <a class="footer-link" href="resources">Resources</a>
</div>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
  let stripe = Stripe('sk_test_123');
  let elements = stripe.elements();
  let style = {
  base: {
    // Add your base input styles here. For example:
    fontSize: '50px',
    color: '#32325d',
  },
};
  let card = elements.create('card', { style: style });
card.mount('#card-element');
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is my partial header that includes the Stripe.js script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <!-- Required Meta Tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Lonestar Firearm Defense</title>
  <!-- Google Fonts -->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Anton&family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Custom CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" href="/images/lonestar.png">
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/5431d76b85.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Stripe.js script -->
  <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Contact Banner -->
  <div class="container-fluid contact-banner-container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>
        <p>Dallas</p>
        <i class="fas fa-phone-alt"></i>
        <a href="tel:888-852-0762">(888)852-0762</a>
        <i class="far fa-envelope"></i>
        <a href="mailto:info@lonestarfirearmdefense.com">info@lonestarfirearmdefense.com</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- Navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
    <!-- Nav Logo -->
    <div class="container d-flex flex-nowrap">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
        <img src="/images/lfd-logo.png" alt="Lonestar Firearm Defense">
      </a>
      <!-- Nav Button -->
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
    <!-- Nav Links -->
    <div id="navbarSupportedContent" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ul-navbar">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/about">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="nav-link" href="/#membershipPlansContainer">Membership</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/contact">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <% if(user) { %>
          <a class="nav-link" href="/user-panel">Hi, <%= user.firstName %></a>
          <%  } else { %>
          <a class="nav-link" href="/register">Signup/Login</a>
          <%  } %>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/blog">Blog</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

It is also weird that neither my navbar nor my footer is being rendered on this page even though they are coded in, so maybe that is an indication that the Stripe elements is working slightly. How can I properly create the checkout form using Stripe Elements?

Comment: Your code is using your Secret API key when initializing Stripe.js which would never work. You have to use the Publishable API key. Stripe.js should output a clear error message in the console about this. You're also calling the Stripe library but don't wait for Stripe.js to have properly loaded. The Stripe could should be in a JS callback for when the DOM is done rendering.

Comment: Well I tried using the publishable key but I got an error that said I cannot use the pk when creating subscriptions for customers. So I added the pk to the script in the checkout page while keeping the secret key in my stripe.js. However, I still cannot render a stripe checkout page, you said I am not correctly loading the stripe.js library but I included it in my header.ejs page which is loaded into the checkout page, so I don't understand what's wrong. Can you explain more on the JS callback to load the stripe code?

Comment: It's unfortunately going to be tricky helping with so much code. You really want to start with a lot less code and then slowly add more complexity. Start by loading Stripe.js client-side and then showing the card element, following Stripe's most basic guide: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment